# Is there a way to schedule a silent notification for a certain time in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, ios10

I'm currently trying wake my app up at a certain time and update data. I know that I can use a silent notification for this, but I'm not sure whether I can schedule said silent notification to be sent at a certain time. Is this at all possible for Swift 3 / iOS 10? If not, is there another way to run code at a certain time, even if my app is not open?

Comment: What framework are you using? I know UNNotification Framework you set a `UNNotificationTrigger` using the time, but I do not think you can trigger the notification without any content. The user has to manually click the notification for it to open up the app in `AppDelegate`'s `didRecieveLocalNotification` method

Comment: Sure, but what I'm essentially trying to do is wake my app up without the user knowing, run some code, and based on that, decide whether to schedule a UNNotification. Thus, sending a UNNotification at that time would not work.

Comment: There is no way. The only way to wake up app is with user input. The only way to schedule a background task is with app in foreground. But that background task will only last for max of around 30 seconds after app leaves foreground.

Comment: Disappointing, but thanks for letting me know. I appreciate the help

Comment: What do you need to do? Maybe with a little more detail I can help you design something. Are you just trying to check once a day whether to schedule a notification or not?

Comment: Basically, wake the app up at a specified time, and check the number of steps taken within the last half hour. I've got code setup to check the steps, but it won't actually run unless the app is in the foreground

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154167/discussion-between-nsgangster-and-spencer-milanak).

Comment: I recommend send a notification from your server, and update the local info after open the notification, its easily